# Laravel - cargar fuente personalizada

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

Estoy intentando cargar una fuente "Fire sans" en mi proyecto laravel, para ello hago lo siguiente

Las fuentes, las he puesto en este directorio /public/vendor/fonts/ , quedando de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego lo que hago es mirar mi archivo app.scss que hace include de distintos ar

**Contenido del fichero app.scss**

```
@import "style";
@import "container";
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
```

Y en el contenido de style.sass tengo esto

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Fira Sans;
    src: url('/public/vendor/fonts/FiraSans-ThinItalic.ttf');
}

h1,h2 {
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    line-height: 1.1;
}
```

Luego ejecuto "npm run watch" y no me produce error, cargo mi página y no tengo errores en la consola ni en network.

Que puedo revisar más?

Gracias,

Comment: ¿_fo**r**tawesome_?, supongo que ahí debería ir una _**n**_: `@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';`

Comment: pues aunque parezca mentira..es correcto

Answer (score 0):

El font-family debería ir entre dobles comillas o comilla simples.
Y en los elementos indicar el font-family; por ejemplo:

```
body {
   font-family: 'Raleway';
   front-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
}
```

Y atento a la compatibilidad con los diferentes navegadores -> indica varias url con los diferentes formatos de fuente (si lo ves necesario).